Email from Deutsche Bahn about a timetable change - what do I need to do?
I booked a journey from Brussels Midi to Essen in a couple of weeks' time. The tickets were booked through raileurope.com. Today I received an email from Deutsche Bahn telling me that due to a timetable change, the journey I was supposed to make can't be carried out as originally planned:

Fahrplanänderung auf Ihrer Reise nach Essen Hbf am 02. Okt. 2024: Fahrt nicht wie geplant möglich [Schedule change on your trip to Essen Hbf on 02 Oct 2024: Journey not possible as planned]
Guten Tag [my name],
Ihre Reise von Bruxelles Midi nach Essen Hbf am 02. Okt. 2024 ist wegen einer Fahrplanänderung nicht wie geplant möglich. [Your journey from Bruxelles Midi to Essen Hbf on 02 Oct 2024 is not possible as planned due to a schedule change]
Mit freundlichen Grüßen
Ihre Deutsche Bahn
Ihr bisheriger Reiseplan (nicht mehr möglich) [Your previous itinerary (no longer possible)]
Auftragsnummer: [a 12-digit number]

(below that point in the email is a description of the planned itinerary for the journey, which involved travel on an ICE train from Brussels to Cologne followed by travel on an RE train from Cologne to Essen)
This email alerts me to the fact that something is wrong, but it does not tell me anything about what I should do about it. It does not even tell me which of the two services I was going to travel on is no longer going to operate. I am at a loss for what action on my part is supposed to be prompted by this notification. What should my next steps be?
If I were travelling on the British railway system, then the faults of that system notwithstanding, I would be confident that I could turn up on the day of travel and if the train I was meant to take isn't operating, take any train on any route that's even halfway reasonable that would allow me to accomplish my journey. It is a standard expectation for travellers on the British rail system that if you buy a ticket in good faith then the rail system as a whole has to enable you to complete the journey, and if trains are cancelled or not running then you get to travel on other trains, even if those other trains are run by completely different companies. I've no idea whether the European rail system operates according to similar principles, as I have insufficient experience of it.
Edit
The trains are ICE 17 and RE 1.

Are you having images displayed in the email? Sometimes, when I felt an email was overly weird or missing information, it turned out that they had important information or even links "hidden" in images.

The email is weird. Try to look where you booked the system, if they updated something. Note: the email is that you cannot travel as planned, not about travel is impossible. Or if you can give us more information, we may check also on DB website, about what alternative they propose.

"if the train I was meant to take isn't operating, take any train on any route that's even halfway reasonable that would allow me to accomplish my journey" — That's more or less how it works for DB as well. You're usually limited to trains on the same route though. If your ticket has a "Via" section, that lists the city abbreviations any alternative train would need to take for the ticket to remain valid.

@deceze - I am not sure that this is still accurate (or maybe just not enforced). When "Zugbindung aufgehoben", all my info and experience points at that you can use any connection that get's you to your target.

@GiacomoCatenazzi in what sense do you find the email weird? For me it sounds quite typical of something sent by DB

Due to the complexity of automatically calculating a new, good route, these emails don't contain a suggested route. This should get rid of train-binding (zugbindung) and let you take any train from your start location to end location, so I guess the expectation is that you ask at an infodesk at a german train station, or just using the db navigator app.

I'll guess that your original itinerary was:
・ Bruxelles Midi
   ↓ ICE
・ Köln Hbf.
   ↓ RE 1
・ Essen Hbf.
Looking at that route for October 2nd now, it has this note:

Der Zug hält ersatzweise in Köln-Ehrenfeld. Bitte prüfen Sie Ihre Reiseverbindung kurz vor der Abfahrt des Zuges.
Train stops in Köln-Ehrenfeld [instead of Hbf]. Please check your connection shortly before departure.

So because of constructions works, Köln Hbf can't be served that day, which makes your original journey impossible. However, instead you'll simply be changing in Köln-Ehrenfeld instead, which shouldn't be too much of a change.
Yes, the email is a bit cryptic about it.

Yes, after looking into it a bit more, I think you're right.

The two existing answers provide a good solution for OPs specific situation but I thought it would be useful to provide some general advice on what one can/ is supposed to do with an email as OP received from Deutsche Bahn in general.
The first issue is about 'Zugbindung' meaning being bound to a specific train. Your original ticket may be with or without Zugbindung depending on the type of ticket. If it has Zugbindung the email from Deutsche Bahn should tell you that the Zugbindung is lifted meaning you are free to take most other connections that lead to your goal (some restrictions apply).
If you ticket has Zugbindung and it is not lifted then (hopefully) the timetable change only affects some part of your journey on trains without Zugbindung (regional trains) and you only need an alternative for that part and are still bound to your original ticket for the rest of the journey.
The second part is to find out where you original connection would actually fail and what the alternatives are. The simplest way is to just check the general Deutsch Bahn website and query it for the exact trip one has already booked. The website should be updated and no longer show the booked connection but rather present alternative connections to the destination. It is also not uncommon that the old connection is still shown but there is a footnote/ warning message attached to it telling you that it currently doesn't run (and possibly why).
Additionally I would recommend to check the new connection again one or two days before the planned departure. It is very possible that the time table changed again and the alternative connection found when DB first send a warning email doesn't exist anymore and a new alternative has to be found. The DB website is also not always up to date with all future timetable changes but should be quite accurate for the next day or two.

You don't say what your original schedule was, but after searching for Bruxelles Midi - Essen Hbf on bahn.de, I suspect the issue is that you now have to change at Köln-Ehrenfeld rather than Köln Hbf.
So just take your original train as planned and change there.

Yes, I think this is true. I tried planning a new journey on bahn.de for that day, and it showed the same train numbers (ICE 17 and RE 1) with a connection at Ehrenfeld instead of the hauptbahnhof (and a little warning about it being a deviation from the normal schedule).
